# How to call an AngularJS filter from pure JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is just for test and learn. I am having a JSON object `obj`.
I want to call angular `Json` filter on that to format that json object and print it on chrome console. Not by any button click. Just by writing code in directly on console of chrome.

I know I can that with some online tool or offline tool as well. But I want to learn how to run a angular defined filter in a plain JavaScript.

Note:

- I can call it in view like `{{obj | Json}}`
- I can also call it from controller as `$filter('Json')(obj);`

But I am not able to call it in pure javascript where angular is appended with script tag but not bootstrapped (started). I am able to access `angular` object though.

I want something like

```
var $filter = angular.filter(); //Since I do not have controller here
console.log($filter('Json')(obj));
```

Comment: To understand more this problem, Suppose you just want to use filter of angular neither controller nor any other thing of angular. Then you will want to call filter directly from your plain JavaScript code. This is what I want to know. It is silly I know, But it could grow our knowledge as hacking angular to use it as pertials ;)

Comment: You need to bootstrap angular to access it, but you could set a global variable and assign it $filter in an app so you could test in console if that's what you want

Comment: Ok thats great. If I asign the filter object to my gobal variable. I understand it now. But come to the first point. How to botstrap and only use filter?

Comment: If you just want to test things.... do it in plunker. Can set up a new app in 15 seconds. Angular isn't a library...it's a framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $filter = $injector.get("$filter");
var obj = {a:1};
console.log($filter("json")(obj));
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3z2yurw/).

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.